# Rack middleware server crash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write simple rack middleware like this:

```
class NewMiddleWare
  NEW_STRING = <<BEGIN                                                                                                  
     my new content
  BEGIN

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    response_body = ""
    response.each {|part| response_body += part}
    response_body += "#{NEW_STRING}"
    headers["Content-Length"] = response_body.length.to_s
    [status, headers, response_body]
  end
end
```

when I run rackup, I got:
`Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method`each`for #<String:0x007fad313bdb30>` in terminal.

I couldn't figure out the reason for this error. Response object 
should be able to respond each right? Coz I saw some sample code doing
that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Rack spec](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC#The_Body):

> The Body must respond to `each` and must only yield String values. The Body itself should not be an instance of String, as this will break in Ruby 1.9.

In Ruby 1.8 Strings did respond to `each`, but that changed in 1.9.

The simplest solution would be to just return an array containing the string:

```
[status, headers, [response_body]]
```